# Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 18.04 cause freeze

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia

I am running a Dell Precision 5540 with Ubuntu 18.04 and an NVidia Quadro T2000.

From `lspci`:

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [Quadro T2000 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
```

From `ubuntu-drivers devices`:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001FB8sv00001028sd00000906bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

My kernel version, from `uname -r`:

```
4.15.0-1079-oem
```

My Ubuntu version information, `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

When I log in and `nvidia` is selected by `nvidia-prime` (that is to say, when nvidia drivers are loaded), I am able to login and after some time the X-server appears to crash, freezing the GUI. I say "freezes the GUI" because if I leave it alone the `dmesg` log continues to grow in the background. In `dmesg` the following errors coincide with the freeze:

```
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer kernel: NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-54fd0cf3-82c7-1f02-af0a-5555977a0327
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer kernel: NVRM: GPU Board Serial Number: 
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 62, pid=617, 203c(3090) 00000000 00000000
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=617, Ch 00000000
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=617, Ch 00000001
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) NVIDIA(0): The NVIDIA X driver has encountered an error; attempting to
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) NVIDIA(0):     recover...
Apr 18 15:08:17 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=617, Ch 00000008
Apr 18 15:08:19 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3247, Ch 00000009
Apr 18 15:08:19 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3247, Ch 0000000a
Apr 18 15:08:19 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3247, Ch 00000010
Apr 18 15:08:20 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3445, Ch 00000011
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3445, Ch 00000012
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3445, Ch 00000013
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3445, Ch 00000014
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3445, Ch 00000015
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=3445, Ch 00000018
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=4331, Ch 00000019
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=4331, Ch 0000001a
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 45, pid=4331, Ch 0000001b
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to allocate notification memory.
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to allocate push buffer
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) NVIDIA(0): Error recovery failed.
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) NVIDIA(0):  *** Aborting ***
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE)
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: Fatal server error:
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) Failed to recover from error!
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE)
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]:          at http://wiki.x.org
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]:  for help.
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/brad/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Apr 18 15:08:21 artificer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3245]: (EE)
```

The `Xorg.0.log` log isn't much more informative.

```
[   139.284] (EE) NVIDIA(0): The NVIDIA X driver has encountered an error; attempting to
[   139.284] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     recover...
[   143.875] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to allocate notification memory.
[   143.875] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to allocate push buffer
[   143.875] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Error recovery failed.
[   143.875] (EE) NVIDIA(0):  *** Aborting ***
[   143.875] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[   143.875] (EE) Failed to recover from error!
[   143.875] (EE)
[   143.875] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[   143.875] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/brad/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   143.875] (EE)
```

I've tried a lot of different solutions, including:

- Installing 440 drivers
- Installing 430 drivers
- Installing 435 drivers
- Installing drivers via `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- Performing `apt --purge remove 'nvidia-*` before each install.

Each time I've done these things there is a consistent "freeze" about two minutes after login. I generally use this time to run `prime-select intel` before the inevitable crash, since the system will not crash with the `intel` GPU selected.

Anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After eliminating a range of potential software causes, this behavior was found to be caused by physical faults in the GPU. The freezing persisted after a full factory restore. Hardware was replaced.